# Limit processor time of individual processes

Tags: linux, scheduling, cpu-usage

We have a shared system/cpu for many students at our university.
Everyone can launch processes and there limits on how much processing power a user can take.

This works rather well except for some occasional cases of not malice but incompetence, where users somehow manage to launch and break a process or have no sense for the runtime of their program.
This can lead to issues such as a texworks-process or a forgotten jar suddenly having 1100 CPU-hours.

Can we somehow offer users to "signal" that a process is actually supposed to take 10/100+h of CPU-time when they launch a process. Ideally without having an impact on users that "casually" use RDP/a webbrowser.

Tools like cpulimit/a maximum amount of usage per user do not seem necessary at the moment and would overshoot the amount of regulation. The limit would ideally be per process and the boundaries should have to be set by the user, not to limit the user, but to specify that "x" amount of cpu-usage is intended, so we can kill or limit processes that *accidentally* take up an unreasonable amount of resources.

Comment: Use cgroups/cpu.